# Can I use Non-Gregorian Recurrence Rules defined in RFC 7529 using calendar provider in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-calendar

I'm using calendar provider in my android app and I need to define events with non-Gregorian recurrence rules which is defined in [RFC 7529](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7529) which is an update to [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545). RFC 5545 is supported according to [Calendar provider overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider), but it is not mentioned if RFC 7529 is supported too.